# How to access a python file using chaincode in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to run a python script using chaincode by this function:

```
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "-c" ,"from land import *;print a.validate_proof(a.get_proof(1),'36e0fd847d927d68475f32a94efff30812ee3ce87c7752973f4dd7476aa2e97e','b8b1f39aa2e3fc2dde37f3df04e829f514fb98369b522bfb35c663befa896766')")
    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        l := fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + string(output)
        return shim.Error(l)
    } else {
        return shim.Success([]byte(string(output)))
    }
```

but I am getting the following error when trying to invoke the chaincode on the channel:

```
chaincode error (status: 500, message: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH:
```

Comment: It looks like node which execute chaincode havn't python installed

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this?  
But as mgosk notes, python is not installed in the image where chaincode runs.